# Django, internationalization mysteriously not working

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, django-templates

In my django project i'm introducing internationalization.
I have followed all tips, particularly:

- inserted trans statement in a template, inserted `{% load i18n %}` on top of template
- i have runned `django-admin.py makemessages -l it` (from root of project)
- i have setted the msgstr of /locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/django.po
- then i have runned `django-admin.py compilemessages (from root of project)`

My settings.py is:

- `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'`
- `USE_I18N = True USE_L10N = True`
- `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSOR = ('django.core.context_processors.i18n',)`
- `"django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",` in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

If i use DjDT for debugging django in web browser, i can see that:

- Accept-Language is 'it'

But instead of seeing the page in it language i continue to see in en-us language.
I have read other questions about this topic on stackoverflow, but i didnt find a solution.
What does my app need to work internationalization?

Edit-1

My project structure is the following:

> src/
>
> ```
>      myproj/
>
>           app1/
>
>           app2/
> ```
>
> locale/
>
> ```
>     it/
>
>         LC_MESSAGES/
>
>                    django.mo
>
>                    django.po
>
>  it-IT/
>
>         ...
> ```
>
> templates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i paste the folder locale (in root of project) in myproj folder the internationalization works, also without setting LOCALE_PATHS settings.py.

Comment: Yes, because locale in myproject is default location for translation. But it should also working if you put it outside and set LOCALE_PATHS properly. I am glad you managed to get it working :)

Comment: @gruszczy I'm too, overall after too time passed on this problem. Have you got a blog? or other pages?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `LANGUAGE_CODE` to italian setting and see, what happens then?

Have you tried setting `LANGUAGES` to both English and Italian and see, what happens? For Polish and English I had something like this: `LANGUAGES = (('pl', 'Polski'), ('en', 'English'))`.

One last thing: are your views using RequestContext?

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                              my_data_dictionary,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Can you create a request context before rendering template and check values of `LANGUAGES` and `LANGUAGE_CODE`:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    context = RequestContext(request)
    print context.LANGUAGE, context.LANGUAGE_CODE
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', my_data_dictionary, 
                              context_instance=context)
```

This way we shall see what value it has set.

I believe RequestContext must be used so the language can be detected inside template.

I remember the pain of setting this up, I once tried to turn this on for Facebook application running on Django. Maybe I can come up with something more.

Comment: Yes, if i set `LANGUAGE_CODE='it'` nothins happens. The result is the same: i see the page in english language.

Comment: I have added this in setting.py: `LANGUAGES = (('it', 'Italian'), ('en', 'English'))` but nothing happens, tha page uses english language yet

Comment: Are you using pure `django` or `django` inside `Google App Engine`?

Comment: Pure django. On localhost - linux

Comment: yes, i use RequestContext in the specific request (about which is interested this topic)

Comment: One more edit. I will check your answer tomorrow. Good night ;-)

Comment: From context debugging: `dict: {'LANGUAGES': (('it', 'Italian'), ('en', 'English')), 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False, 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'it'}`

Comment: I am perplexed. Is there any way I could look at your code? Or maybe you can create a small project, recreate all steps you took and see, if you still have a problem? This way you could show me this small project and maybe I could find the problem.

Comment: i will think about it, if i cannot resolve alone i create a small project, test localization on it, and if it doesn't work i contact you. However thanks for the helps.

Comment: If you find the answer, please tell me. I'd love to know, what was the problem.

Comment: I have also noted that if i put `{% trans 'Edit Profile' as p %} {{ p }}` as specified in documentation it throws template syntax error only option for 'trans' is 'noop'. Hope this would be able to help a solution.

Comment: I have edited the question: now it is described project folder structure

Comment: So I understand locale doesn't have to be in `myproj`. But then, have you set properly `LOCALE_PATHS` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#locale-paths)?

Comment: Before, i didn't have LOCALE_PATHS in settings.py. Now i have setted properly it, adding it the right path-to-locale-folder but it continues to not working.

Comment: gruszczy: i have built an other small project to test localization, but this not working in it too. So i want to send you this project, but i cannot find your contacts, please send me to bitliner.service@gmail.com

Comment: Finally!!! If i paste the folder locale (in root of project) in myproj folder the internationalization works, also without setting LOCALE_PATHs settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Django is not finding your locale folder. See the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/i18n/

By default django will look under each installed app and in the root of the project (which is the folder containing your settings.py file - not necessarily the root directory of your apps)